# How to assign n day target variables in machine learning

Tags: programming, machine-learning, prediction, forecasting

I am trying to forecast future price using supervised machine learning. My logic is to take open and close price from **t,  t-1, t-2 and t-3** period to predict future close price in the period **t+1,t+3 and t+5**

```
library(quantmod)
symbol= getSymbols("AAPL",from="2010-03-01", auto.assign=F)
close<-Cl(symbol)
open<-Op(symbol)
lc1<-lag(close)
lc2<-lag(close,2)
lc3<-lag(close,3)
lo1<-lag(open)
lo2<-lag(open,2)
lo3<-lag(open,3)
X<-cbind(close,open,lc1,lc2,lc3,lo1,lo2,lo3)
Y<-need to assign close price for t+1,t+3 and t+5
```

I have created feature vectors using lag function for period 0,1,2 and 3 but my question is how to I assign target variable for t+1, t+3 and t+5 periods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign each of the target variables to their own column and then train a model for each of your forecast horizons

```
library(quantmod)
symbol= getSymbols("AAPL",from="2010-03-01", auto.assign=F)
close<-Cl(symbol)
open<-Op(symbol)
lc1<-lag(close)
lc2<-lag(close,2)
lc3<-lag(close,3)
lo1<-lag(open)
lo2<-lag(open,2)
lo3<-lag(open,3)
X<-cbind(close,open,lc1,lc2,lc3,lo1,lo2,lo3)
```

Add outcome variables (Y)

```
X$t1<-lag(close,-1)
X$t3<-lag(close,-3)
X$t5<-lag(close,-5)
```

From this you can nou train 3 models to predict the closing of $t+n, n=1,..,n$

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be doing is actually an [auto-regressive (AR) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), so perhaps you can benefit from using existing models like [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARIMA) R already has [great](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html) [implementations](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/auto.arima) for.